# iOS 11 refresh control + search bar = missing spinner when refreshing

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to use the standard `UIRefreshControl` and `UISearchController` on a `UITableViewController`. However it doesn't look like it does what it's supposed to. When refreshing, scrolling leaves the navigation bar with a big blank area, presumably where the spinner is supposed to be:

[image]

I have a sample project [on GitHub](https://github.com/allen-zeng/iOS11RefreshControlBug). Here's how the controls are set up:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let spinner = UIRefreshControl()
    spinner.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl = spinner

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

I've tried assigning the refresh control to the property on `UITableView` instead of the one on `UITableViewController`, that doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone come across the same issue?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too.  It works correctly for me if I remove the search bar or if I add the search bar as the table view's header instead of setting it to the navigationItem.  Looks like a bug when the navbar tries to handle both.

Comment: I have this problem too. Unless I remove the searchbar by "self.navigationItem.searchController = nil" I get a crash.

Comment: I got in touch with Apple, they have confirmed that it's a bug.

Answer (score 10):

You can use UIRefreshController in the old way, which is like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let spinner = UIRefreshControl()
    spinner.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(spinner)

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate and assign the refresh control every time the table view controller appears on screen.

If you subclassed `UITableViewController`:

```swift
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    ...

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl(...)
    }
}
```

If you use view controller containment:

```swift
class MyContainerViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let tableViewController = UITableViewController(style: .plain)

    ...

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableViewController.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl(...)
    }
}
```